# Scrape the data after giving date criteria using input box

Tags: excel, vba

i need your help on the below code. I am scraping the data from the website based on date criteria. i have the code till it open the page  from the specific date which i give through input box, After that it moves to new page where i have data under headings Product(s), Manufacturer, NOC with conditions, Notice of Compliance date, Medicinal ingredient(s) and DIN(s). i need to copy that data into excel. Could any please help me with the code how to copy the data?
below is my code till it enter the new page.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Canada_Sorucing()

Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim mynocFromDate As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
.Visible = True
.navigate ("https://health-products.canada.ca/noc-ac/index-eng.jsp")
While IE.Readystate <> 4 Or IE.busy: DoEvents: Wend
mynocFromDate = InputBox("enter from date eg.2016-10-01, yyyymmdd")
IE.document.all("nocFromDate").Value = mynocFromDate
IE.document.getElementsByName("action").Item.Click
Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").ClearContents

'from here i need to copy data under headings Product(s)    ,Manufacturer   ,NOC with conditions    ,Notice of Compliance date  ,Medicinal ingredient(s)    and DIN(s)
            
End With
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: Use document inspector to get the names of the elements and use those to get the values

Comment: i tried it but failed to execute. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav

Comment: Nathan, could you please with code for one Element I would try for other.http://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav

Comment: thank You very much Nathan i would try it and let you know. Sorry for delay reply as i was busy. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav

Answer (score 0):

Using the MS Internet Controls and MS HTML Library, I'd start by doing the following.

```
Sub Canada_Sorucing()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim col As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim mynocFromDate As String

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE

    .Visible = True
    .navigate ("https://health-products.canada.ca/noc-ac/index-eng.jsp")

    While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    mynocFromDate = InputBox("enter from date eg.2016-10-01, yyyymmdd", , "2016-10-01")

    Set doc = IE.document

    With doc
        .getElementById("nocFromDate").Value = mynocFromDate
        .getElementById("action").Click
    End With

    Do While IE.busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    '   Here's your start
    MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("TR")(1).innerText
    Set col = doc.getElementsByTagName("TR")

End With

IE.Quit

End Sub
```